# Azure Data Factory (Data Flow) - Non existent column appearing in data preview

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a dataset (of a csv file existing in ADLS Gen2) in ADF Data Flow. The first time I tried to do a Data Preview, all the columns from the raw file was being shown properly. Then I removed the first column from the csv file and refreshed the Data Preview tab. The first column is still being shown in the preview. But the column is greyed out and contains NULL values.

[image: BrandID was the column removed from the csv file]

BrandID was the column removed from the csv file but is still appearing the preview tab. I deleted the dataflow and created a new one but still the issue remains.

Here is a screenshot of the source tab:

[image]

I have tried with Allow schema drift as 'On' and 'Off'. Neither has any effect on the issue. I am not sure where I am wrong here. Has anyone faced this issue? Any pointers would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The preview is kind of "cache" from my experience. It will stay at the "cached" version when you load the dataset. You can enforce a refresh by editing the dataset. The simplest way would be renaming the dataset, refresh the preview, and renaming the dataset back.

Comment: @ray Thanks for the quick response. I renamed the dataset and refreshed but its still shows the column. The data preview available in the "Dataset" shows the correct columns. The projection tab of the Data flow too shows the correct ones. Only when the Data preview gets refreshed it brings back the old column. Is there any other workaround that you could suggest?

Comment: Hi @Abhra Ray, Can you try renaming the Output stream name of the source transformation where the dataset is referred?

Comment: Hi @NiharikaMoola-MT I did not add any transformation yet. The flow only has a source step. I deleted the datasets and created new ones for now to carry on with the development. But I shall try your suggestion if I change the data again and face the same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mapping needs to be refreshed

Navigate to Source Setting -> Dataset Open -> Schema -> Import schema .

Come back to Data preview -> Refresh

Before

[image]

After
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems to work. Although, I moved my datasets to inline ones but I ll keep this one for future references.